# Не поворачиваются картинки на мобильном устройстве с использованием php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть сайт с картинками, которые подгружаются из базы данных и отображаются на сайте в ряд. Необходимо реализовать функционал поворота данных картинок. Реализовал поворот при помощи данного кода:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); 
$rotate = imagerotate($image, $degree, 0); 
imagejpeg($rotate, $path);  
imagedestroy($image);
```

Проблема в том, что на компьютере данный код отлично отрабатывает и картинки поворачиваются без проблем, а вот на мобильном устройстве картинки вообще не поворачиваются. Подскажите в чём может быть причина?

Comment: Причина в том, что картинки **в любом случае** поворачиваются **на сервере**. И если на мобильном они не поворачиваются, то проблема в клиентском коде, который не может запросить повернутую картинку. А не в РНР.

Comment: А почему на компьютере и телефоне возникает разное поведение?

Comment: Извините, я сегодня забыл свой магический шар дома. И карты таро куда-то запропастились. Как только найду, то сразу вам напишу, по какой причине не работает код, который я никогда в жизни не видел.

Comment: Хорошо, буду ждать

Comment: @Jour так поди он хочет с одного сайта скачать, отзеркалить и у себя сохранить, при чем тут css?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы поворот сохранялся навсегда. Это можно сделать на стороне клиента? Если да, то каким образом?

Comment: есть малюсенькая вероятность, что у вас в картинке есть EXIF в котором указано где верх, и он подхватывается мобильным браузером, а десктопным нет. Но это прям очень сомнительно (что в принципе браузер может смотреть на exif).

Comment: @teran да, похоже проблема всё-таки в браузере. Я попробовал повернуть картинки в другом мобильном браузере и там всё отлично отрабатывает, так же как и на компьютере. В Хроме почему-то возникает проблема с поворотом. Либо он кеширует данные об ориентации картинок выведенных на сайте (хотя после сброса кэша, ничего не меняется), либо что-то ещё, без понятия. EXIF тут, наверное, не причем, так как при помощи кода, который я написал создаётся новая картинка и насколько я понимаю EXIF там уже другой.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#112902 а тут вроде как написано что exif сохраняется.

Comment: бразуер если кэширует то саму картинку, а не ориентацию. Если вы на фронте получили картинку, потом тыкаете кнопку чтобы ее повернуть, и обновляете ее, при этом имя файла остается тем же самым, то да, вероятно браузер закэшировал ее и все. Добавьте к ней какой нить рандомный параметр в путь `/path/to/image.jpg?ts=...` где ts это текущий unix_timestamp. Собственно если вкладку сетевой активности посмотреть, то там все видно, что кэшировано, а что нет

Comment: @teran немного не понял - куда нужно добавлять этот параметр и в какой момент - при создании новой картинки или при выводе уже готовой картинки на экран?

Comment: у меня тут тоже магического шара нет. я не знаю как процессы отображения и поворота у вас вообще связаны. Чтобы избежать кэширования в браузере, то добавлять надо очевидно при выводе на экран. Вопрос только в том, что вам не всегда его добавлять надо, а когда вы ее изменили только. В общем без описания процесса, что у вас происходит, дальнейшие (как впрочем и предыдущие)  рассуждения тут пальцем в небо.

Comment: Я не пойму какой конкретно код нужен?? Я поворачиваю картинку при помощи кода, который я написал выше (при этом я вижу как эта картинка в папке (с картинками) поворачивается, то есть всё отрабатывает как надо). И далее я просто вывожу эту картинку на экран при помощи html в тэге img.

Comment: Я думаю, тут стоит пересмотреть вопрос. Мы уже выяснили, что РНР тут не при чем, и картинки поворачиваются. я быпредложил удалить вопрос, как изначально неверно поставленный, и задать новый, на основе уже новых данных о поведении кода.

Comment: @Ипатьев и что от этого изменится? Сразу же дадут ответ на мой вопрос? Если у кого есть какие-то пути решения, то и здесь напишут, а если нету то и в новом вопросе будут писать ПрЫкОлЫ про магические шары.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу на свой же вопрос.
Выяснялось, что некоторые браузеры (по всей видимости большинство популярных: chrome, firefox) кешируют, выведенные на сайты картинки. То есть сохраняют их в памяти такими, какими они были загружены на сайт когда-то давно и такими же и отображают. Поэтому как бы вы фактически не изменяли картинку - в браузере эти изменения всё равно отображаться не будут. Поможет только очистка КЕША веб-содержимого (на примере браузера firefox).

Один из путей решения данной проблемы: необходимо при выводе изображения на сайт - добавлять к нему какой-либо параметр с уникальным значением (спасибо за наводку @teran), например так (если вы используете php):

```
<?php $name = "photo1.jpeg"; ?>
<img src="uploads/<?echo $name."?t=".time(); ?>">
```

Кстати говоря, в Яндекс браузере такой проблемы нет. Изначально я пользовался им на компьютере, поэтому думал, что на компьютере всё работает как надо, а на мобильном устройстве по какой-то причине поворот не отображается. Оказалось всё дело в разной работе браузеров.